# website which configured with webmin always redirects to default apache2 index file

Tags: debian, apache2, webmin

i am trying to install my website on apache 2 on debian 9 using webmin
but the problem is website keeps redirect to index.html file from apache's default

in /etc/apache2/sites-available i have niaqo.com.conf which contains this code

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/niaqo.com"
ServerName niaqo.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/niaqo.com">
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled also has same file as top niaqo.com.conf which has these code

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/niaqo.com"
    ServerName niaqo.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/html/niaqo.com">
    allow from all
    Options None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

any kind of help is appreciated since i am new with this..i already configures my bind using webmin correctly cause when i go intodns.com/niaqo.com i can see that domain names set correctly
whenever i open the website it keeps redirecting me to /var/www/html and shows me default html page from apache2 with https.which i don't even need https on this website since i don't have ssl cert

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`? For example, `000-default.conf`. Or a similar filename with `default` in it. It is the Apache default virtual host configuration file and, if you don't need it, disable it with `sudo a2dissite`:
`sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`